# Web-scrape bonds information from nasdaqomxnordic

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium

I'm a newbie getting into web scrapers. I've made something that works,  it takes 3.2 hours to complete job and randomly have 10 lines blank each time I run this job. Help is much appreciated!

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


def getBrowser():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    global browser
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    s = Service('''C:\\Users\\rajes\\yogita\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe''')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('''C:\\Users\\rajes\\yogita\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe''')
    return browser


def getISINUrls(browser):
    url = 'http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/bonds/denmark/'
    browser.get(url)
    browser.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(1)
    bonds = {}
    try:
        getUrls(browser, bonds)
        pg_down = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                       "#bondsSearchDKOutput > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr > td.pgDown")
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", pg_down)
        time.sleep(1)
        while (True):
            # pages = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'bondsSearchDKOutput')
            getUrls(browser, bonds)
            pg_down = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                           "#bondsSearchDKOutput > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr > td.pgDown")
            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", pg_down)
            time.sleep(1)

    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        pass
    return bonds


def getUrls(browser, bonds):
    hrefs_in_table = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@href]')
    count = 0
    for element in hrefs_in_table:
        href = element.get_attribute('href')
        if 'microsite?Instrumen' in href:
            bonds[element.text] = href
            count += 1


def saveURLs(bond):
    filename = "linkstoday.txt"
    fo = open(filename, "w")
    for k, v in bonds.items():
        fo.write(str(v) + '\n')
    fo.close()


def getSleepTime(count):
    first = 1
    res = 1
    i = 0;
    while i < count:
        i += 1
        temp = res
        res = temp + first
        first = temp
    return res


def getISINData(browser2):
    with open("linkstoday.txt", "r") as a_file:
        denmark_drawing = []

        for line in a_file:
            result_found = False
            count = 2
            Isin_code = str()
            short_name = str()
            Volume_circulating = str()
            Repayment_date = str()
            Drawing_percent = str()
            wait_time = getSleepTime(0) + 1
            while not result_found and count < 5:
                stripped_line = line.strip()
                browser2.get(stripped_line)
                browser2.maximize_window()
                time.sleep(getSleepTime(count) + 1)
                WebDriverWait(browser2, 1).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ui-id-3 > span'))).click()
                time.sleep(getSleepTime(count))
                Isin_code = browser2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#db-f-isin').text
                short_name = browser2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#db-f-nm').text
                Volume_circulating = browser2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#db-f-oa').text
                Repayment_date = browser2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#db-f-drd').text
                Drawing_percent = browser2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#db-f-dp').text
                if Isin_code == " ":
                    count += 1
                else:
                    result_found = True
            temp_data = [Isin_code,
                         short_name,
                         Volume_circulating,
                         Repayment_date,
                         Drawing_percent]
            denmark_drawing.append(temp_data)
    # Writing data to dataframe
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(denmark_drawing,
                       columns=['ISIN', 'Shortname', 'OutstandingVolume', 'Repaymentdate', 'Drawingpercent'])
    df3.to_csv('Denamrkscrapedsata_20220121.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = getBrowser()
    print(f'''Call to getISINUrls start at: {datetime.now()}''')
    bonds = getISINUrls(browser)
    print(f'''Call to getISINUrls ends at : {datetime.now()}''')
    print(f'''total records: {len(bonds)}''')
    browser.close()
    browser2 = getBrowser()
    print(f'''Call to getISINData start at: {datetime.now()}''')
    getISINData(browser2)
    print(f'''Call to getISINData ends at : {datetime.now()}''')
    saveURLs(bonds)
    browser2.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Scraping will always be slow. If you're serious about this, get access to [Genium/INET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inet).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereas it would be nice to use an official API, I don't see any.

Scraping is morally ambiguous and in each case you need to think about the impact to the service. In this case I don't feel too bad about doing it.

If you were to keep using Selenium, don't use BeautifulSoup: your browser already has a DOM, so you don't want a secondary library doing HTML parsing. But much more importantly, don't use Selenium at all, and don't even hit the HTML URLs themselves. Invest some time in reverse engineering and you'll see that the data actually come from a (strange, inconsistent, poorly-designed) API that is exposed unauthenticated to the internet. You can see traffic to this API in the developer tools of your favourite browser.

Don't call `sleep`. Even if you were to keep Selenium, there are better ways to wait for conditions to be met.

Don't save the URLs: instead, just save the instrument IDs.

Don't use Pandas, since you're just writing to a CSV file; use the built-in CSV support.

Don't `exit(0)` at the end; that's redundant.

### Suggested

```
import csv
from typing import Iterator, Iterable, Literal
from xml.etree import ElementTree

from requests import Session, Response


class APIError(Exception):
    pass


def fetch_data(
    session: Session,
    xml_query: str,
    bond_type: Literal[
        'doMortgageCreditAndSpecialInstitutions',
        'doGovernment',
        'doStructuredBonds',
    ] = 'doMortgageCreditAndSpecialInstitutions',
) -> Response:
    with session.post(
        url='http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx',
        headers={
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        },
        cookies={'bonds_dk_search_view': bond_type},
        data={'xmlquery': xml_query},
        timeout=5,
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()

    if resp.text == 'Invalid Request':
        raise APIError()
    return resp


def get_isin_ids(session: Session) -> Iterator[str]:
    xml_query = '''<post>
<param name="Exchange" value="NMF"/>
<param name="SubSystem" value="Prices"/>
<param name="Market" value="GITS:CO:CPHCB"/>
<param name="Action" value="GetMarket"/>
<param name="inst__an" value="ed,itid"/>
<param name="XPath" value="//inst[@ed!='' and (@itid='2' or @itid='3')]"/>
<param name="RecursiveMarketElement" value="True"/>
<param name="inst__e" value="7"/>
<param name="app" value="/bonds/denmark/"/>
</post>'''

    xml_response = fetch_data(session, xml_query).text
    doc = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_response)
    for institution in doc.findall('./inst'):
        yield institution.attrib['id']


def save_ids(ids: Iterable[str]) -> None:
    with open('linkstoday.txt', 'w') as fo:
        for id in ids:
            fo.write(id + '\n')


def get_isin_data(session: Session, ids: Iterable[str]) -> Iterator[dict[str, str]]:
    for id in ids:
        xml_query = f'''<post>
<param name="Exchange" value="NMF"/>
<param name="SubSystem" value="Prices"/>
<param name="Action" value="GetInstrument"/>
<param name="inst__a" value="0,1,2,5,21,23"/>
<param name="Exception" value="false"/>
<param name="ext_xslt" value="/nordicV3/inst_table.xsl"/>
<param name="Instrument" value="{id}"/>
<param name="inst__an" value="id,nm,oa,dp,drd"/>
<param name="inst__e" value="1,3,6,7,8"/>
<param name="trd__a" value="7,8"/>
<param name="t__a" value="1,2,10,7,8,18,31"/>
<param name="json" value="1"/>
<param name="app" value="/bonds/denmark/microsite"/>
</post>'''

        doc = fetch_data(session, xml_query).json()['inst']
        record = {
            'ISIN': doc['@id'],
            'ShortName': doc['@nm'],
            'OutstandingVolume': doc['@oa'],
            'RepaymentDate': doc['@drd'],
            'DrawingPercent': doc['@dp'],
        }
        yield record


def save_csv(records: Iterable[dict[str, str]]) -> None:
    with open('DenmarkScrapeData.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(
            f=f, fieldnames=(
                'ISIN',
                'ShortName',
                'OutstandingVolume',
                'RepaymentDate',
                'DrawingPercent',
            ))
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(records)


def main() -> None:
    with Session() as session:
        session.headers = {
            'User-Agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) '
                'Gecko/20100101 '
                'Firefox/96.0',
        }

        ids = tuple(get_isin_ids(session))
        print(f'total records: {len(ids)}')
        save_ids(ids)

        records = get_isin_data(session, ids)
        save_csv(records)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

This output comes from letting the program run for a few seconds and then cancelling it:

```
ISIN,ShortName,OutstandingVolume,RepaymentDate,DrawingPercent
XCSE-0:5_111.E.33,"-0,5 111.E.33",84493151,2022-01-01,2.8112571826
XCSE-0:5_PCT_111.E_2030,"-0,5 pct 111.E 2030",665797291,2022-01-01,3.2633533803
XCSE-0:5RDS20S33,"-0,5RDS20S33",451515514,2022-01-01,2.9740738964
XCSE-05NYK01EA30,-05NYK01EA30,878951074,2022-01-01,3.3091375583
XCSE-05NYK01EA33,-05NYK01EA33,881317489,2022-01-01,2.8425761917
XCSE0_111.E.33,0 111.E.33,653907754,2022-01-01,2.4804408498
XCSE0_111.E.38,0 111.E.38,564600489,2022-01-01,1.855852439
XCSE0_111.E.43,0 111.E.43,176772175,2022-01-01,1.3165659355
XCSE0_PCT_111.E.30,0 pct 111.E.30,1029518700,2022-01-01,5.9398552916
XCSE0_PCT_111.E.40,0 pct 111.E.40,1977182808,2022-01-01,1.554107146
XCSE0:0_42A_B_2040,"0,0 42A B 2040",209526702,2022-01-01,1.7771871286
XCSE0:0_ANN_2040,"0,0 Ann 2040",56394289,2022-01-01,1.5425031762
XCSE0:00NDASDRO30,"0,00NDASDRO30",1224109240,2022-01-01,3.8723465773
XCSE0:0NDASDRO33,"0,0NDASDRO33",860502381,2022-01-01,2.2338528235
XCSE0:0NDASDRO40,"0,0NDASDRO40",1459255905,2022-01-01,1.4938027118
XCSE0:0NDASDRO43,"0,0NDASDRO43",236599645,2022-01-01,1.3792804762
XCSE0:0RDSD20S33,"0,0RDSD20S33",718629368,2022-01-01,2.4815379285
XCSE0:0RDSD21S35,"0,0RDSD21S35",3462720875,2022-01-01,2.0717949411
XCSE0:0RDSD21S38,"0,0RDSD21S38",2251018344,2022-01-01,1.7993154025
XCSE0:0RDSD22S40,"0,0RDSD22S40",2011886347,2022-01-01,1.4705608857
XCSE0:0RDSD22S43,"0,0RDSD22S43",184303670,2022-01-01,0.8792686726
XCSE0:5_111.E.38,"0,5 111.E.38",338880761,2022-01-01,1.3969909037
XCSE0:5_411.E.OA.53,"0,5 411.E.OA.53",1393252566,2022-01-01,0.0591983882
XCSE0:5_42A_B_2040,"0,5 42A B 2040",8131539033,2022-01-01,1.3671120294
XCSE0:5_ANN_2040,"0,5 Ann 2040",451401810,2022-01-01,2.4906658405
XCSE0:5_ANN_2050,"0,5 Ann 2050",653730646,2022-01-01,0.8698109475
XCSE0:5_B_2043,"0,5 B 2043",3606287111,2022-01-01,1.2922558113
XCSE0:5_B_2053,"0,5 B 2053",1642437254,2022-01-01,0.8121455742
XCSE0:5_OA_2050,"0,5 OA 2050",99003000,2022-01-01,0.0
XCSE0:5_OA_43A_B_2050,"0,5 OA 43A B 2050",482048871,2022-01-01,0.0
XCSE0:5_OA_B_2053,"0,5 OA B 2053",219089000,2022-01-01,0.0
XCSE0:5_PCT_111.E.27,"0,5 pct 111.E.27",283502208,2022-01-01,8.3610097198
XCSE0:5_PCT_111.E.35,"0,5 pct 111.E.35",1583753306,2022-01-01,2.5446722633
XCSE0:5_PCT_111.E.40,"0,5 pct 111.E.40",6407716782,2022-01-01,1.4303071825
XCSE0:5_PCT_111.E.50,"0,5 pct 111.E.50",10350998334,2022-01-01,0.9164192286
XCSE0:5_PCT_411.E.OA.50,"0,5 pct 411.E.OA.50",3087755141,2022-01-01,0.0671974779
XCSE0:50_43_A_B_2050,"0,50 43 A B 2050",1343369361,2022-01-01,0.8540709785
XCSE0:5NDASDRO27,"0,5NDASDRO27",481074018,2022-01-01,8.803025784
XCSE0:5NDASDRO30,"0,5NDASDRO30",881168727,2022-01-01,7.5241365836
XCSE0:5NDASDRO40,"0,5NDASDRO40",11220224408,2022-01-01,1.5304442894
XCSE0:5NDASDRO43,"0,5NDASDRO43",5986915933,2022-01-01,1.3334597191
XCSE0:5NDASDRO50,"0,5NDASDRO50",9229180944,2022-01-01,0.8712084834
XCSE0:5NDASDRO53,"0,5NDASDRO53",6247426527,2022-01-01,0.8375194931
XCSE0:5NDASDROOA50,"0,5NDASDROOA50",5461281793,2022-01-01,0.0083519478
XCSE0:5NDASDROOA53,"0,5NDASDROOA53",3175404000,2022-01-01,0.0
XCSE0:5NYK01EA27,"0,5NYK01EA27",1269241062,2022-01-01,8.7144274945
XCSE0:5NYK01EA30,"0,5NYK01EA30",1753360650,2022-01-01,6.3398581018
XCSE0:5NYK01EA35,"0,5NYK01EA35",3850470214,2022-01-01,2.2289106154
XCSE0:5NYK01EA38,"0,5NYK01EA38",2292707137,2022-01-01,1.6186901466
XCSE0:5NYK01EA40,"0,5NYK01EA40",25051403176,2022-01-01,1.410155416
XCSE0:5NYK01EA50,"0,5NYK01EA50",23594969156,2022-01-01,0.8777441213
XCSE0:5NYK01EDA50,"0,5NYK01EDA50",9778359698,2022-01-01,0.010495042
XCSE0:5NYK01EDA53,"0,5NYK01EDA53",7720300441,2022-01-01,0.0015823625
XCSE0:5NYK01IA43,"0,5NYK01IA43",152247394,2022-01-01,1.2410533255
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.8 and getting error,     def get_isin_data(session: Session, ids: Iterable[str]) -> Iterator[dict[str, str]]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable.   I have copied your code with no changes. Could you please help me with this. Thanks .

Comment: The code I've showed is for Python 3.10, to which you should upgrade. The reason for the failure is that built-ins cannot be used as type hints (dict, tuple, etc.) in 3.8.